# What is the stochastic aspect of Word2Vec?

Tags: nlp, gensim, word2vec

I'm vectorizing words on a few different corpora with Gensim and am getting results that are making me rethink how Word2Vec functions. My understanding was that Word2Vec was deterministic, and that the position of a word in a vector space would not change from training to training. If "My cat is running" and "your dog can't be running" are the two sentences in the corpus, then the value of "running" (or its stem) seems necessarily fixed.

However, I've found that that value indeed does vary across models, and words keep changing where they are on a vector space when I train the model. The differences are not always hugely meaningful, but they do indicate the existence of some random process. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is well-covered in the [Gensim FAQ](https://github.com/RaRe-Technologies/gensim/wiki/Recipes-&-FAQ#q11-ive-trained-my-word2vecdoc2vecetc-model-repeatedly-using-the-exact-same-text-corpus-but-the-vectors-are-different-each-time-is-there-a-bug-or-have-i-made-a-mistake-2vec-training-non-determinism), which I quote here:

> #### Q11: I've trained my `Word2Vec`/`Doc2Vec`/etc model repeatedly using the exact same text corpus, but the vectors are different each time. Is there a bug or have I made a mistake? (*2vec training non-determinism)
>
> **Answer:** The *2vec models (word2vec, fasttext, doc2vec…) begin with random initialization, then most modes use additional randomization
>   during training. (For example, the training windows are randomly
>   truncated as an efficient way of weighting nearer words higher. The
>   negative examples in the default negative-sampling mode are chosen
>   randomly. And the downsampling of highly-frequent words, as controlled
>   by the `sample` parameter, is driven by random choices. These
>   behaviors were all defined in the original Word2Vec paper's algorithm
>   description.)
>
> Even when all this randomness comes from a
>   pseudorandom-number-generator that's been seeded to give a
>   reproducible stream of random numbers (which gensim does by default),
>   the usual case of multi-threaded training can further change the exact
>   training-order of text examples, and thus the final model state.
>   (Further, in Python 3.x, the hashing of strings is randomized each
>   re-launch of the Python interpreter - changing the iteration ordering
>   of vocabulary dicts from run to run, and thus making even the same
>   string-of-random-number-draws pick different words in different
>   launches.)
>
> So, it is to be expected that models vary from run to run, even
>   trained on the same data. There's no single "right place" for any
>   word-vector or doc-vector to wind up: just positions that are at
>   progressively more-useful distances & directions from other vectors
>   co-trained inside the same model. (In general, only vectors that were
>   trained together in an interleaved session of contrasting uses become
>   comparable in their coordinates.)
>
> Suitable training parameters should yield models that are roughly as
>   useful, from run-to-run, as each other. Testing and evaluation
>   processes should be tolerant of any shifts in vector positions, and of
>   small "jitter" in the overall utility of models, that arises from the
>   inherent algorithm randomness. (If the observed quality from
>   run-to-run varies a lot, there may be other problems: too little data,
>   poorly-tuned parameters, or errors/weaknesses in the evaluation
>   method.)
>
> You can try to force determinism, by using `workers=1` to limit
>   training to a single thread – and, if in Python 3.x, using the
>   `PYTHONHASHSEED` environment variable to disable its usual string hash
>   randomization. But training will be much slower than with more
>   threads. And, you'd be obscuring the inherent
>   randomness/approximateness of the underlying algorithms, in a way that
>   might make results more fragile and dependent on the luck of a
>   particular setup. It's better to tolerate a little jitter, and use
>   excessive jitter as an indicator of problems elsewhere in the data or
>   model setup – rather than impose a superficial determinism.

Answer (score 1):

While I don't know any implementation details of Word2Vec in gensim, I do know that, in general, Word2Vec is trained by a simple neural network with an embedding layer as the first layer. The weight matrix of this embedding layer contains the word vectors that we are interested in.

This being said, it is in general also quite common to initialize the weights of a neural network randomly. So there you have the origin of your randomness.

But how can the results be different, regardless of different (random) starting conditions?

A well trained model will assign similar vectors to words that have similar meaning. This similarity is measured by the cosine of the angle between the two vectors. Mathematically speaking, if `v` and `w` are the vectors of two very similar words then

```
dot(v, w) / (len(v) * len(w)) # this formula gives you the cosine of the angle between v and w
```

will be close to `1`.

Also, it will allow you to do arithmetics like the famous

```
king - man + woman = queen
```

For illustration purposes imagine 2D-vectors. Would these arithmetical properties get lost if you e.g. rotate everything by some angle around the origin? With a little mathematical background I can assure you: No, they won't!

So, your assumption

> If "My cat is running" and "your dog can't be running" are the two
>   sentences in the corpus, then the value of "running" (or its stem)
>   seems necessarily fixed.

is wrong. The value of "running" is not fixed at all. What is (somehow) fixed, however, is the similarity (cosine) and arithmetical relationship to other words.